# Can I detect whether the user has tapped a blue status bar to open an app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location

Is is possible to check whether the app became active, b/c of user has tapped the blue bar, not the application icon itself?

### [image: A blue bar]

For example:

1. User opens application with `When in use` location permission;
2. Application starts updating location through the location manager;
3. User dismisses application and see the blue bar;
4. **User taps blue bar, application becomes active** (UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification is thrown)

So in this case I want to be sure that the application became active exactly b/c of the user was interested in this blue bar and tapped on it, to show some hint for them.

Comment: No, your application just becomes active. The reason for your use of background location should already be obvious to the user (e.g. in the google maps case they have asked for directions)